# Max temperature for lager carbonation

Tags: beer, carbonation, lager

Although I'm an experienced homebrewer, I've only ever done ales because I've never had a fridge.  I recently bought a BrewJacket and was able to brew my first lager.  I'm now at the bottling phase and have a question about the temperature.

I keep my house at 78°F(25°C).  I've seen the posts where carbonation can take place at 60-70°F and be fine.  Is there any risk carbonating at the higher 78 F temperature?  I don't have a fridge to put the beers in.

If it matters, the beer is a Marzen that lagered at 54 F for four weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is that temps above 80F will promote staling and reduce the shelf life of the beer.  I doubt that a week or so at that temp or slightly above would be too detrimental, though.  I don't think you'll have any problem at all carbing at 78F.